# Can't understand how $-a/b + c$ should equal $- (a - b*c) / b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is it so that -$\frac{a}{b}$ + c equals -$\frac{a - bc}{b}$ and not -$\frac{a + bc}{b}$? I can't really see it.

I understand we first do  -$\frac{a}{b}$ + $\frac{bc}{b}$, but why **bc** should be negative when we add it to the numerator? I know it's probably a stupid question but I just can't see it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we get $$c-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{bc-a}{b}=-\frac{a-bc}{b}$$ if $b\ne 0$
but $$-\frac{a+bc}{b}=\frac{-a-bc}{b}$$

Answer (score 0):

Fractions behave as parentheses. What happens in the numerator (if we include the sign in front of the fraction) is that $-a + bc$ becomes $-(a-bc)$. Can you see that these two are equal? And how $-(a + bc)$ is different?